# How is direct use of return value different from local variable

Tags: c#, html, struct, ref

`Memory<T>` was introduced to me as "a wrapper around `Span<T>` so you can use `Span` in async/iterator methods". I understand why `Span` cannot be used in async, but `ref struct` types got me thinking that I never understood the concept of arguments and return values properly. Saying "use `Memory.Span` to create `Span` as argument in async method because you cannot use `Span` in async methods" sounds counterintuitive to me. Explained in code:

```cs
async Task<ReadOnlyMemory<char>> GetMemory(string text) => text.AsMemory();
async Task foo(string text)
{
    var memory = await GetMemory(text);

    // this is valid code
    ConsumeSpan(memory.Span);

    // this is invalid code
    var textSpan = memory.Span;
    ConsumeSpan(textSpan);
}
```

The valid code behaves the same as the invalid code. Wondering if `Memory.Span` can have some speciall behavior implemented in CLR I tried this:

```cs
Span<char> CreateSpan() => new Span<char>();
async Task bar(string text) {
    // both statements are valid
    CreateSpan();
    _ = CreateSpan();
}
```

Which falsified my suspition and made me realize that I may have a wrong mental model about values living in methods. Is there something different in C# language about values which have name and which don't? Probably answering my own question, value with name is the definition of a variable so there must be some difference between variables and "unnamed values". Will there be a local copy of Span created on the stack in my foo method when I use it directly as function argument or that is something that language doesn't specify and leaves that for the optimizer to decide? Do you think differently about unnamed values in your day-to-day programming? Looking at ref returns makes me break my assumptions about unnamed variables too:

```cs
int x = 0;
ref int GetRef() => ref x;
void foobar()
{
    GetRef() = 42;
}
```

Comment: This question is a like a *whirlwind adventure*. I'm finding it hard to deduce the actual question from the musings (for which there are many). Do you want to know why you cant use a ref struct in an async method ? or ways you can use them...

Comment: I understand why and how you can use ref struct, it's just that creating it without assigning to a variable was surprising to me. My question(s) are in the last paragraph, primarily I am asking if people are thinking differently about variables and unnamed values, because this is first case for me that they produce different *behavior* (behavior might be the same, but the language constructs around them is different).

Answer (score 1):

There's one key difference between what you call "named variables" and other variables. In release mode, both behave the same. But in debug mode, the lifespan of named variables is extended until the end of the scope, so that the debugger can inspect them at any time.

Basically, consider the following code:

```
async Task bar(string text) 
{
    var a = GetValue();
    await Task.Yield();
}
```

If you put a breakpoint on the closing brace `}`, if running in debug mode, you will be able to inspect the value of `a`. In release mode, the value will be optimized away.

That's why writing `var a = CreateSpan()` is illegal in an async method. It could possibly be safe in some conditions in release mode, but it'll cause the scope of the variable to be extended in unsafe ways in debug mode.